# embedding a website inside of a angularjs app

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to embed a website inside of an angularjs app? For example, I'm looking to embed jaspersoft's UI inside of an angular app, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html tag [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) in your view.

For example:

```
<iframe src="https://google.com"></iframe>
```